# Performance: I have some parseable text. Save parsed vs. save raw and parse on requested

Tags: regex, performance, parsing, database-design

Firstly i am sorry for that terrible English.

I hope I could duly explained my concern. My concern is performance.

I have some well-designed text and i should parse that with RegExp before publishing. Should i save it raw or parse and save? By the way if i parse and save that, then i should save raw copy, because the user may want to edit the entry later.

that is a raw sample:

```
lorem [b]ipsum[/b] do`lor` sit amet.
```

and that is a parsed sample:

```
lorem <b>ipsum<b> do<span class="some">lor</span> sit amet.
```

P.S. my project is reading intensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the ability to edit the raw value, then you have to keep the raw value. So the choice is to save just the raw, or both the raw and the cooked. I'd say to just store the raw.

Disadvantages of storing both:

1. Takes twice as much disk space. This may or may not be an issue of itself these days as disk space is cheap -- depends on how much text you need to store if it will add up to a lot. But every record is now twice as large and so you have to read twice as much. Or if you store it separately, you have twice as many records and you have to do joins when you need both.
2. You have to worry about keeping the two synchronized. If the algorithm for cooking the data changes, do you update every record? If not, how do you keep track of which have been updated and which not? This could get complicated.

The obvious disadvantage is:

1. You have to re-run the cooking function every time you display a record.

But how much work is this? How long does it take to run? My guess is, Not very long. Probably less time than it takes to read a longer record. That is, it may well be faster to recook every time than to save the cooked result. Even if not, the penalty is probably small.

The only way to say definitively is to set up a test and compare the run times.